# Odd scatter plot in RStudio

Tags: r, ggplot2, scatter-plot

I'm trying to make a scatter plot of latitude and longitude. My code is as follows:

```
graf_disp <- ggplot(dados, aes(x=Latitude, y=Longitude)) +
  geom_point(aes(col=Circuito)) +
  labs(subtitle = "Localizacao dos circuitos",
       y = "Longitude", x = "Latitude")
 
plot(graf_disp)
```

And the plotted graph is the following:
[image]

I don't understand why there are grey lines covering the rest of the graph. Can anyone help me with this?
Thanks.

Comment: Could you please share your data using head(`dput(dados)`, 20)?

Comment: From the image you posted I would guess that your `Latitude` and `Longitude` columns are characters or factors instead of numerics, i.e. the grey lines are labels overlapping each other. Check your data and try with converting to numerics.

Comment: @stefan oh you're right! thanks for reminding me!